How can I build a superconductor at home?
How can I make a superconductor at home? I have been interested in making one from scratch, but I have no idea where to begin. I have heard about YBCO superconductors and I feel as though that is the correct route to go down for me due to it being supposedly easier that the other methods, but I have no idea where to begin. Is there an easier one that any of you guys have heard of? Any tips on where to start or tips for the creation process itself? Also what materials will I need?

As mentioned below, if you want to use liquid nitrogen (easier and cheaper than liquid helium), YBCO is your best shot. Opposite to what some say, it is quite easy to make "demonstration grade" YBCO. You will need some equipment that is available in several high schools. Paul Grant (a superconductivity scientist) wrote a recipe for it. You can find it in this pdf file.

Lead is a superconductor. So is aluminum and mercury and many other metals. Question is how cold is your house?
Synthesizing a known type-II superconductor such as YBCO at home from raw ingredients will honestly be very difficult and expensive. If you are curious about superconductivity and want to experiment with it, YBCO can be purchased relatively cheaply online, liquid nitrogen to cool it below it's critical temperature can be purchased from welding supply companies- although you will need a dewar to store it in and proper safety to handle it.
You sound like you are fresh on your journey to understanding condensed matter and potentially a younger scientist- if this assessment is correct, I implore you to continue being curious and mystified by things like superconductivity but realize that for something such as this there is no cookbook or tips or tricks for making a superconductor in general! If we knew such rules it would not be an active area of research.

If you're asking about growing YBCO, making thin film samples at home would require, at minimum:

Glass substrates to grow the films on
An ultrasound bath (500-1500 usd)
Various solvents and high purity chemical powders which contain the species which make up YBCO
A spin coating/deposition system (~ 5000 usd) for evenly coating your substrates with the relevant solutions
A muffle furnace (~7000-10000 usd) for annealing your samples at high temperature
The many years of experience and experimental skill required to grow high quality, complex crystals (priceless)

(Procedure taken from this paper)
Or you could simply buy a chunk of YBCO online for several orders of magnitude less cost.
